# where to get the diff of changes in the default sshd_config between versions?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I was doing a `apt-get upgrade` for `openssh-server` from version `1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4` to  `1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5`.

During the update it shows

```
A new version (/tmp/filehQFzF3) of configuration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.
```

Because the changes were made as part of a `cloud-init` script I want to check what I need to update in that script. For this I need the diff of the original `sshd_config` in `1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4` and `1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5`.

From the changelog at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5 however it seems that the config file has not been changed. Now I am confused.

This is the output of the diff from the interactive upgrade:

```
Line by line differences between versions                                      
│                                                                                
│ --- /etc/ssh/sshd_config root.root 0644 2022-01-30 22:45:30                    
│ +++ /tmp/filehQFzF3 root.root 0644 2022-05-26 19:43:13                         
│ @@ -31,15 +31,15 @@                                                            
│  # Authentication:                                                             
│                                                                                
│  #LoginGraceTime 2m                                                            
│ -PermitRootLogin no                                                            
│ +#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password                                            
│  #StrictModes yes                                                              
│ -MaxAuthTries 2                                                                
│ +#MaxAuthTries 6                                                               
│  #MaxSessions 10                                                               
│                                                                                
│  #PubkeyAuthentication yes                                                     
│                                                                                
│  # Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.        
│ -AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys                                       
│ +#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2                
│                                                                                
│  #AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none                                                
│                                                                                
│ @@ -55,7 +55,7 @@                                                              
│  #IgnoreRhosts yes                                                             
│                                                                                
│  # To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!                
│ -#PasswordAuthentication yes                                                   
│ +PasswordAuthentication no                                                     
│  #PermitEmptyPasswords no                                                      
│                                                                                
│  # Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with    
│ @@ -85,10 +85,10 @@                                                            
│  # and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.                                
│  UsePAM yes                                                                    
│                                                                                
│ -AllowAgentForwarding no                                                       
│ -AllowTcpForwarding no                                                         
│ +#AllowAgentForwarding yes                                                     
│ +#AllowTcpForwarding yes                                                       
│  #GatewayPorts no                                                              
│ -X11Forwarding no                                                              
│ +X11Forwarding yes                                                             
│  #X11DisplayOffset 10                                                          
│  #X11UseLocalhost yes                                                          
│  #PermitTTY yes                                                                
│ @@ -121,5 +121,3 @@                                                            
│  # AllowTcpForwarding no                                                       
│  # PermitTTY no                                                                
│  # ForceCommand cvs server                                                     
│ -PasswordAuthentication no
```

and this is the part of the `cloud-init` script to configure sshd:

```
  - sed -i -e '/^PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^PasswordAuthentication/s/^.*$/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^X11Forwarding/s/^.*$/X11Forwarding no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^#MaxAuthTries/s/^.*$/MaxAuthTries 2/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^#AllowTcpForwarding/s/^.*$/AllowTcpForwarding no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^#AllowAgentForwarding/s/^.*$/AllowAgentForwarding no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^#AuthorizedKeysFile/s/^.*$/AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh\/authorized_keys/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Now my question is, whether the `sed` commands are still doing what we want in the new version. To figure it out, I need to understand how the new default config looks like that we would use when creating a new instance with this `cloud-init` script.